# Grakn data validation and updating schema

Tags: database, vaticle-typedb, vaticle-typeql

So I'm using Grakn and wanted to know how Grakn handles existing schema updates.

If I have this schema:

```
person sub entity, has name;
```

and I want to extend it with:

```
person sub entity, has name, has age;
```

How is this done in Grakn if there's already data present? Do I need to be careful to migrate my data when I extend my schema?

Answer (score 0):

Extending a schema (ie - `define` new functionality) is always allowed, as long as the new schema components all satisfy the standard schema validation.

Using `undefine`, is more tricky, for instance, because you cannot undefine schema types that still have instances in the data. Attempting to do so will throw an exception.

There's a third class of operations where using `define` can *mutate* a schema, such as modifying a `key` to be a `has` or a `has` to be a `key`. However, many of these operations are tricky and will throw exceptions if not very careful.